# Planar UV on multiple instanced objects

Tags: displacement, instances

I have a pin table I created, sort of like the one in this video:

https://youtu.be/jVDZKXtYCzs

I've exported it as an alembic to Unreal and it works great.
I want to map an image of a world map to the top.  Create sort of a war table.

Is there a way to planar map one image that goes on top of all these pins vs an image on each individual pin?
Thank you for any tips or direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In doing a bit more research, I came across this tutorial, which answers my question around 10:30.  Hopefully this helps someone:

https://youtu.be/_zXbPRYpi5I